# OpenGL texture tiling/repeating with matrix

Tags: opengl, graphics, 3d

I know you can do texture tiling/repeating in OpenGL by setting the texture coordinates to values greater than 1.0 (eg 2.0) but is there a way I can do texture tiling with the OpenGL texture matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure

Your input UVs are multiplied by the texture matrix to give the actual UVs.

If you input (1,1,0,0) and want (2,2,0,0), such a matrix could be

```
2 0 0 0
0 2 0 0
0 0 1 0
0 0 0 1
```

Of course, this is just an example, but your question is quite generic.